# Resultado de busca SQL em tabela no front-end

Tags: php, html, sql, front-end

Galera, estou desenvolvendo um projeto para a faculdade e queria colocar o resultado da busca feita no banco mysql em uma tabela no front-end, porém estou com dificuldades para fazer isso, existe algum meio prático de se fazer isso??

Valeuu

Comment: qual dificuldade? nos mostre o seu código, fica mais fácil de ajudar.

Comment: Leia [essa pergunta aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132), em [especial essa resposta aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/132) para entender o que há de errado com a sua pergunta.